# Android Virtual KeyboardView... How to get keyboardView or how to get Keyboard height but with no resize screen

Tags: android, view, keyboard

I have a SurfaceView in background and i don't want to move it up with resizing screen. I need to get virtual Keyboard View or Height of a Keyboard so i can move my EditText on other place and other View need to be on their places. Here is my code below

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_relative_layout">

<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_surfase_view"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_bottom_menu_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="View My Events"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_view_my_events_button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_schedule_broadcast_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Schedule Broadcast"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Follow"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_follow_button"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Go Live"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_go_live_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<EditText
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/main_screen_edit_text"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:layout_above="@id/main_fragment_bottom_menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
<com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_following_users_list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_below="@id/main_fragment_following_users_list"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_chat_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/main_screen_edit_text"/>
```